# How to know if the token is ERC20 or ERC233?

Tags: blockchain

as I stated on the title because I am very confuse on how to know if the token is ERC20 or ERC233. I bought Thore Cash on Mercatox and I didnt know if it is ERC20 or ERC233 but they said they supported the swap but i just want to make sure.

Comment: It's easy to spot by looking at the contract code. Why not post the address of the token contract for those who aren't familiar with it? You're looking for a call to `tokenFallback()` in the token's `transfer()` function. That is the definition of ERC223.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and reliable way to determine which standard a token is following is to look at its source code. The easy and fairly trustable path to that is to

1. head over to [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io)
2. find the token by searching for its address or name
3. double check with a trusted source that you got the right smart contract address, there are thousands of fake token contracts out there. Take it from one of your own transactions for example.
4. In the Profile Summary on the right, click the contract address, then click the "contract" tab
5. hit ctrl+F or cmd+F and search for ERC. This will probably yield ERC20 and possibly other numbers corresponding to other types of tokens, which usually are a superset of ERC20.

If that does not yield satisfactory results:

6. search for a piece of code that is specific to this kind of token, e.g. as suggested by Rob Hitchens for ERC233: "tokenFallback", or "extcodesize", which must appear in the transfer function.

Answer (score 0):

ERC-223 transfer to contracts consumes less gas than ERC-20.

Comment: Can you give more details? or an example where it shows

Comment: Refer to https://medium.com/wepower/erc-standards-to-move-ethereum-forward-erc-20-erc-223-erc-721-e1712456449d

Comment: The article has the same answer but it shows no proof or any other evidence.

Comment: This is plain wrong. An ERC-223 transfer function is the exact same code as an ERC20's with the addition of some code to check for the destination's "extcodesize", revealing if the tokens landed on a smart contract (in which case it reverts the tx if the smart contract can't handle ERC233). So it can only cost more gas. ERC233 have many other advantages though. cf. https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/blob/master/token/ERC223/ERC223_token.sol#L55